# How to create queue methods?

Tags: java, methods, interface, queue, implementation

I have a project for a java training where I have to create a class that implements Queue interface and all its methods! After the implementation I need to create the bodies for all the methods but I'm not sure how. I can't use any implementation from Collection, such Arraylist, LinkedList etc. If I can't use that, where do I store all the elements? Can you give me an example for one method?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't given me enough information. I don't know what methods does Queue interface include and what you really need. However, I did create the following code with may or not help you.

```
public interface Queue<T> {
    T getFirst();
    T getLast();
    T getMid();
    T getIndex(int index);
}


public class Toilet<T> implements Queue {

    private T[] list;

    public Toilet(T... list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setList(T[] list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public T[] getList() {
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public T getFirst() {
        return list[0];
    }

    @Override
    public T getLast() {
        return list[list.length-1];
    }

    @Override
    public T getMid() {
        return list[list.length/2];
    }

    @Override
    public T getIndex(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < list.length) return list[index];
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```